# How to find non duplicate strings in a file

Tags: c, string

I have a problem, i need to find how code appear in a file.
The problem is that in this file the code could appear more than one time and i need to consider only one.

I try to write a function that count how code are in the file (discarding the duplicated code) :

```
int calcolo (struct sistema *sis,int l) {
    char nome[l][6];
    int i=2,a=1,h;


    strcpy(nome[1],sis[1].codice);
    h=1;

    while(i<l) {
        for(a=1;a<=h;a++) {
            if(strcmp(nome[a],sis[i].codice)==0) {
                i++;    
                break;
            }   
        }

        h++;
        strcpy(nome[h],sis[i].codice);
        i++;    

    }
    return h;
}
```

The input file is:

```
2015-03-03 07:01 X100 8.1
2015-03-04 08:02 X100 15.2
2015-03-18 13:15 X100 31.9
2015-08-02 13:10 B209 32.0
2015-08-15 12:01 B209 35.4
2016-01-02 10:44 A101 8.1
2016-02-02 15:41 X100 13.2
```

I don't know how to "bypass" the second part of the while if i didn't recognize any duplicate string.
So the result is 3 that represent the tree code(X100 B209 A101) but i received 5, why?

Comment: On a (possibly) unrelated note, you *do* know that array indexes are based on zero? I.e. the first element have index `0`.

Comment: You show the input file (which is good, many askers don't do this), but you should also show us the expected output, that would make the question much clearer. And you should read this: [mcve]

Comment: Gave OP the answer but the question is written so poorly or they want you to write the answer out for them verbatim and i got downvoted. simply not worth answering

Comment: Please clarify what you expect your code to do, or in other words why you are expecting 5 instead of 3

Comment: It is not easy as comparing the strings. It is enough that the duplicate code will appear in the code in slightly different way for example one space more) and string comparison method will fail. The problem is really complicated - it is a common task for the optimising compilers to find duplicate code - and trust me - it is algorithmically extremly hard to solve problem. Abstracting from the analyse and parse the input stream

Comment: @MichaelWalz It was written in the description, the expected output is 3 but i received 5 because the codes (X100 B209 A101) are three.

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna i just want an help or an alternative way to solve my program not that someone give me the correct program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i know, but the program is a list that start to one, so i decided to lost a little bit of memory for simplify the logic.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Ok,thanks i'll try an alternative or simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, I know it's not a better way to use goto but i need to skip the second part of the code, i've "solved" it:

```
int calcolo (struct sistema *sis,int l) {
    char nome[l][6];
    int i=2,a=1,h;


    strcpy(nome[1],sis[1].codice);
    h=1;

    BACK:   
         while(i<l) {
             for(a=1;a<=h;a++) {
                 if(strcmp(nome[a],sis[i].codice)==0) {
                     i++;
                     goto BACK; 
                 }  
             }
             h++;
             strcpy(nome[h],sis[i].codice);
             i++;   

         }
    return h;
}
```

Output:
Obtained 3 - Expected 3

I would prefer not to use the goto then if someone had some other resolving path in mind, let me know, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Put each new string into a set. Then you use like this :

```
set<string, FOO>::iterator it = set.find("X100");  
if(it != set.end()) // if "X100" was not found
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry but `set` is in C ?!
I think that is only avaible in C++

Comment: https://github.com/avsej/hashset.c check here, and yes, i didn't look to post tags to see "C" instead of "C++"

Comment: Thanks it could be useful

Comment: Just imagine now these data structures are like primitives. It's a must to have them.